# Weird R behavior with indexing function arrays

Tags: r, function, lambda

I'm having some unexpected behaviour in R with function arrays, and I've reduced the problem to a minimal working example:

```
theory = c(function(p) p)

i = 1
posterior = function(p) theory[[i]](p)
i = 2

posterior(0)
```

Which gives me an error saying the subscript `i` is out of bounds.

So I guess that `i` is somehow being used as a "free" variable in the definition of `posterior` so it gets updated when I redefine `i`. Oddly enough, this works:

```
theory = c(function(p) p)

i = 1
posterior = theory[[i]]
i = 2

posterior(0)
```

How can I avoid this? Note that not redefining `i` is not an option, as this stuff is going in a for loop where `i` is the index.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  The error is due to referencing an index that doesn't exist in your function and would be expected.  What your function does isn't different than `c(1)[[2]]`

Comment: @manotheshark Right, so I'm asking if there's a way to get R to immediately evaluate `posterior` rather than do so lazily.

Comment: I think a simpler example is possible. `f = function() letters[i]`. Since `[i]` is not defined in the function or passed in as an argument, the function will look at its parent environments when it is called for a value of `i`. The function is the same whether or not `i` is defined before the function. The function will check for a value of `i` when it is called.

Comment: Ah ok. So I just need to pass `i` as a variable to the function. Thanks @Gregor.

Comment: That would work well---assuming you can pass the value of `i` that you want at the time you call it. Otherwise, I would point you to reading about [functionals](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html) rather than about lazy evaluation.

Comment: @Gregor I'm aware of functionals, but I'm not sure what they'd have to do here.

Comment: I see -- the idea is you just separately define the functional that produces the function from the existing function and call the functional in the loop. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this doesn't work is that you redefine `i = 2`, and then you are out of bounds of theory, which contains a single element. The function is evaluated lazily, so that it only executes `theory[[i]]` when the function is called, at which point `i` equals 2.

You can read some more about lazy evaluation [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html).

Comment: I figured that's what's going on, but how can I fix it? Can I "turn off" lazy evaluation?

Comment: You can't simply 'turn off' lazy evaluation, unfortunately. Depending on exactly what you want to do there might be more or less idiomatic ways of getting around the problem.